# Java Hashtable#hashCode() implementation broken?

Tags: java, hashtable, hashcode

I'm wondering if the default implementation of Java's `Hashtable#hashCode()` is broken when the `Hashtable` contains only entries with identical keys and values per pair.

See for example the following application:

```java
public class HashtableHash {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Hashtable<String, String> ht = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        final int h1 = ht.hashCode();
        System.out.println(h1); // output is 0

        ht.put("Test", "Test");

        final int h2 = ht.hashCode();
        System.out.println(h2); // output is 0 ?!?

        // Hashtable#hashCode() uses this algorithm to calculate hash code
        // of every element:
        //
        // h += e.key.hashCode() ^ e.value.hashCode()
        //
        // The result of XOR on identical hash codes is always 0
        // (because all bits are equal)

        ht.put("Test2", "Hello world");

        final int h3 = ht.hashCode();
        System.out.println(h3); // output is some hash code
    }
}
```

The hash code for an empty Hashtable is 0. After an entry with the key `"Test"` and value `"Test"` has been added to the Hastable the hash code **still** is 0.

The problem is that in Hashtable's `hashCode()` method the hash code of every entry is calculated and added to the hash code as follows

```
h += e.key.hashCode() ^ e.value.hashCode()
```

However `XOR` on identical hash codes (which is the case for identical Strings) is always 0. So entries with identical keys and values are not part of the Hashtable's hash code.

This implementation is *imho* broken because the Hashtable actually has changed. It shouldn't matter if key and value are identical.

Comment: Yep! It's pretty bad. But for compatibility reasons it can't be changed, ever.

Comment: I'm wondering why this was downvoted because it's a legit question and could save somebody some trouble. I've been looking for hours to find a bug which was caused by this behavior.

Comment: You *can't* rely on a different hashcode just because the object is different. Would you say the hashCode is also broken if I add two completely different objects and the hashCode also stays the same? In that case every possible hashcode implementation is broken if the universe of possible objects is larger than 2^32..

Comment: It's more of an observation than a question. (Though not my downvote.)

Comment: So you would use a more complex hashcode that would still run into exactly the same problem for a different combination of input and claim an improvement? Well, to each his own I assume :) Also contrary to say string whose hashcode is documented, it'd be just fine to change the hashCode here. Can't see a real improvement there (assuming hashcodes uniformly distributed over the whole int range) and could break some broken applications, but certainly possible.

Comment: I'm aware of the contracts of `equals()` and `hashCode()`. To clarify what I mean with "broken" is that I (maybe mistakenly) assumed a consistent behavior of `hashCode()` for a specific class. Either the values are part of the calculation or they're not. But border cases like here are just the source of confusion and bugs. So yes, while Hashtable's `hashCode()` may follow the contract the implementation is far from perfect.

Comment: @Voo: Any hash function of a non-trivial type is going to have collisions.  I think the complaint here is that in some tables the percentage of key/value pairs where the key and value have the same hash is far greater than one in four billion (indeed, in some use cases it could be 100%!).  Replacing the xor with an addition would be a zero-cost improvement.  It wouldn't be "perfect", but would avoid a common systematic horrible case.

Comment: @supercat And for situations where the hash code is the negative of another items hashcode you get exactly the same behavior, you just exchange for what values it happens - that's hardly an improvement.

Comment: @Voo: Hash tables where every key and value are identical are a fairly common usage case.  Is there any common usage case where every key's hash code would be the negative of its corresponding item?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation on [hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode());

> It is *not* required that if two objects are unequal according to the
>   equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
>   each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
>   However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>   integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>   hashtables.

In other words, bad implementation - perhaps. Broken - not according to the spec.

Answer (score 5):

It’s not broken, it’s working as designed and advertised. The hash code of two `Map`s being equal does not require the two `Map`s being equal.

Answer (score 1):

The only requirement of `hashCode` is that if two objects are equal, then their hash codes must be equal. Thus

```
public int hashCode() {
    return 123;
}
```

is perfectly valid, although not optimal.